# Install SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

When I try to install SQL Server 2014 from file, I see this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkcQT.jpg)

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you connected with the internet properly?

Comment: I think it's just a warning. Are you blocked completely from this step or Could you able to proceed further?

Comment: Thanks but when I finished the installing ,it had error

Comment: The Same error? or a different one? Please post that error

Comment: yes,the same eror